# Nest : Writing queries for ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nest

I have recently downloaded elasticsearch for a project I have to do in asp.net mvc. I have also downloaded Nest in order to help me doing the queries and to connect with the database.

Although, I can't really understand the Nest documentation, how to query and get the results of the query itself and map them into C# objects.

Furthermore, how do I make a query similar to the _search ?

Sorry if this sounds stupid, but I have been trying to read and learn the documentation for two days and can't really figure it out.

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: No worries, here to help :) Did you see the documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html? If you're completely new to Elasticsearch and NEST, it would be worth going through https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/tree/master which should help in getting up and running. Be sure to use the `codecomplete-2.x` branch if using Elasticsearch 2.x and NEST 2.x. I have a task to merge it into `master` when I get a chance :)

Comment: Ok, I will take a look.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the long awaited answer, but I was away and started to work again today. Are the older versions still good to use ? I understand them better and they have better documentation than the newest one.

Comment: NEST 1.x is still supported and should be used against Elasticsearch 1.x (it's not compatible with Elasticsearch 2.x). NEST 2.x _should_ be more closely aligned with the json query DSL than 1.x. Is there a particular piece that's not clear in 2.x?

Comment: Yes it is. I think I managed to connect to my elasticsearch, but I dont get how to query and get the results via code.